# In iPhone iPhone 6 plus there is a margin on right and left side of full width components

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

In iPhone iPhone 6 plus there is a margin on right and left side of full width components.

i added a full width image and added auto layouts. but in iPhone 6 plus screen there is a margin on left and right side of image view.

Comment: I also having the same issue. It works perfectly with all devices except iPhone 6P.

Comment: Did you constrain your items to the superviews margin or to the superview's edge? By default, in iOS8, it will constrain to the margins (8pt away from the edge).

Comment: @KerrM : That was exactly the mistake. You saved my day.

Comment: @KerrM:Thank you. it helped. I don't have rep to upvote yours.

Comment: I've added it as an answer for people in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, in iOS8, auto layout will constrain views to their superview's margin (8pt away from the edge). To avoid this, you can constrain the view to it's superview's edge by unticking the "Constrain to margins" checkbox in the Pin contextual menu or by using the Editor->Pin->Leading/Trailing Space to superview top menu item.